# Prepros 6: can't parse Private Key error

Tags: ssh, rsa, sftp, prepros

I'm having trouble configuring SFTP with Prepros 6. I’m using the exact same SFTP configuration as I did with Prepros 5, which always worked. SFTP, same Remote Path, same Host, same Port (22), same username, same Private Key.  I copy the contents of a .pem file into the Private Key field.

The first time I try to upload a file from the FTP page, I get the error

> An error occurred while uploading file via FTP.  Cannot parse private key: unsupported key format.

On subsequent attempts, there is no error message but the spinning working icon appears but never goes away and the file is never transferred.  I have to restart Prepros to get the error message again.

The .pem file I’m using has the header -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Is Prepros expecting the file path or the contents of the certificate? Can I paste the contents into the Private Key field like in Prepros 5?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 6.0.7 (March 01, 2017), confirmed by myself.
https://prepros.io/changelog

Comment: Agreed.  This is fixed. Thanks to Subash for the quick fix.